# Backbone views automatically fed options object in initialize method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am curious as to why my Backbone views automatically have an options object in the initialize function like so:

```js
initialize: function (opts) {
    //opts object contains properties like 'context' and 'prevObject', what is that?
    this.options = opts || {};
}
```

as you can see here (zoom in with ctrl +)

[image]

However, Backbone collections do not have any predefined arguments in the initialize function. Why the inconsistency?

I am instantiating my views with empty constructors like so:

```
new HomeView();
```

So I know that I am not explicitly passing any options to the views.

So it must be something that Backbone is doing behind the scenes but I would like to know what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't pass anything through unless you pass something in the constructor. Is HomeView extending off of vanilla Backbone.View?

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log(arguments); // 0 args
    }
});

new MyView();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0gv4svLx/

Comment: yes, it is just extending the vanilla Backbone.View, no other inheritance is happening

Comment: pretty weird, haven't figured it out yet, will let you know if I do

Comment: nevermind it was just one of my views that was being passed an el in the constructor, so that explains it, in any case you are correct, thanks for the hint, will delete the question